# Uninstall Debian while keeping grub entried of other OS

Tags: debian, dual-boot, grub, uninstall

I have 3 OS on my laptop: Windows, Ubuntu, Debian (installed in such order) and Debian at the top of grub entries.

I hope to uninstall Debian while keeping Windows and Ubuntu the way they are. The closest solution I can find is [OS Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) but uninstalling Debian just doesn't work: "applying change" took more than 30 min with no message at all.

Is there any safe solution to delete Debian without destroying grub?

Comment: Whose grub is default boot? If Debian, you need to make sure you are booting with Ubuntu's grub. Are all systems in same boot mode, all UEFI or all BIOS? If all same, just boot into Ubuntu and reinstall grub. `sudo grub-install` If ESP mount in fstab, it will auto reinstall grub in UEFI mode. If old BIOS, better to post link from Boot-Repair so we can see details. Boot-Repair's advanced mode lets you choose an install & choose drive to install boot loader into. You may need to remove UEFI boot entry & /EFI/Debian folder in ESP.

Comment: @oldfred Debian is now the default boot. Under Ubuntu, `$ [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS` prints `UEFI`. so that means Ubuntu was install under UEFI? I think Debian was also installed in UEFI. by `sudo grub-install` do you mean setting Ubuntu as the default boot?

Comment: Booting Ubuntu and reinstalling grub will reset it to default. You could just use sudo efibootmgr and its -o option to set boot order. See `man efibootmgr`You can remove /EFI/Debian folder in ESP and remove the UEFI boot entry with efibootmgr -b Details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228